# Get HTML element by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, protractor

How can I reach the first row and the first column (using javaScript) from a table in specific URL?

for example in the following URL:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp

In 'Table Object Methods', I want to get "createCaption()" .

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this isn't a forum or a coding service. You need to show us what you've tried, in code, and what you want to do/the result. There is effort required for asking questions. In this way StackOverflow is able to be referenced for questions of a similar nature.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...

you get value into rows of table HTML.

```
var row = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using css you can do

```
var elem = element.all(by.css('table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1)').last();
```

This selects the first column from the second row that is in a table.
Using element.all because there are 3 tables it could apply to, which is why you need the .last() because the table you wanted referenced was the last table. Would work better if the table has an unique ID to reference it with.